# java.lang.Exception: The OperationDesc was not synchronized to a method of SoapSkeleton

Tags: java, soap, skeleton-code

I am trying to have a method that does not accept any parameters, but I am having an issue with the Skeleton class.

```
    static {
        org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc _oper;
        org.apache.axis.description.FaultDesc _fault;
        org.apache.axis.description.ParameterDesc [] _params;

        _params = new org.apache.axis.description.ParameterDesc [] {
            new org.apache.axis.description.ParameterDesc(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.utl.com/test", "PingRequest"), org.apache.axis.description.ParameterDesc.IN, new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"), java.lang.String.class, false, false),
        };
        _oper = new org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc("ping", _params, new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.url.com/test", "PingResponse"));
        _oper.setReturnType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        _oper.setElementQName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "Ping"));
        _oper.setSoapAction("http://www.url.com/test/Ping");
        _myOperationsList.add(_oper);
        if (_myOperations.get("ping") == null) {
            _myOperations.put("ping", new java.util.ArrayList());
        }
        ((java.util.List)_myOperations.get("ping")).add(_oper);
```

When I run this program I get this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: The OperationDesc for ping was not synchronized to a method of com.test.www.url.SellerServicesSoapSkeleton.
```

Which I guess make sense because it is describes accepting a parameter despite not having one. I am just not sure how to change it so it doesn't accept anything.

When I run the same code on a method that accepts parameters then everything is fine.